# express redirect sets statusCode to 200 instead of 302

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my case, I want to do a redirect from a post.

```
router.post('/saveUser', function(req,res) {

      // code to call service and get saved userId....

      res.redirect('viewUser/{savedUserId}');
});

router.get('ViewUser/:userId', function(req, res) {
       // here am expecting the res.statusCode to be 302 but instead it is 200

       console.log('StatusCode' + res.statusCode);
       res.render('views/User');
});
```

Am expecting res.statusCode to be 302 instead it is coming as 200. I have tried the below other options too, but no ,luck

```
res.redirect(302, 'viewUser/{savedUserId}');

res.statusCode = 302;
res.setHeader('Location', 'viewUser/{savedUserId}');
res.end();
```

In the ViewUser route, I want to determine whether it is a redirect or not, depending on that, the view will change a little bit.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Comment: As far as I understand, the `res` object in your second handler is a newly created one, not the one you called `.redirect()` on. And it has its statusCode set to 200, the default value. To change the view depending on whether a redirect happened or not, you could use a variable; just add one to your script, set it in '/saveUser' and reset it in '/viewUser'.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG.. thats what am figuring out too. instead of setting a new variable am going to use the referer on the req.headers to figure out whether it is a redirect or not

Comment: @binndur or add an identifier to the redirect url (`res.redirect('viewUser/{savedUserId}?redirect=true')`).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep am trying to avoid that, adding a querystring param just to differentiate a redirect. Looking for any existing paramaters like referer in req.headers to do the job. Do you think referer is not a good idea ?

Comment: @binndur referer sometimes doesn't get sent (although it's generally not something to worry about)

Comment: also I want the users to bookmark the view user page, if I add a query string param for redirect that will get bookmarked and when requested later we will end up hitting the redirect logic, that's another reason why I want to avoid adding a querystring param